# Ruby OAuth gem repository?

Tags: ruby, oauth, open-source, rubygems, repository

I cannot find the repository hosting the latest version of the [oauth gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/oauth) (v 0.4.7).

I've got the [pelle/oauth](https://github.com/pelle/oauth) github repository wich host the 0.4.3, and a link to the supposedly up-to-date [oauth/oauth-ruby](https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby) which is down.

Am I missing something or is this repository now off the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's down. You could grab the code from https://github.com/canadaduane/alfred2-dropbox/blob/master/ruby-1.8/gems/oauth-0.4.7

Answer (score 6):

Artifactory pro will cache gem repositories so even if rubygems.org is down, the package will still be available once you've used it the first time. See [the link](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/RubyGems+Repositories) on how to configure everything. It's pretty simple.

1. Create a repo in artifactory for the gems
2. Execute `gem source --add http://${your_artifactory_name_and_port}/artifactory/api/gems/${your_repo_name}`

That's all you need to do if you're just caching. Storing your locally generated gems takes a bit more effort. See (the link above)[[http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/RubyGems+Repositories]](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/RubyGems+Repositories%5d) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The upstream repository is in GitHub, but with a different organisation name:

https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/